# asterisk SIP User-to-User

Tags: asterisk, sip, transfer

I am trying to make a SIP transfer from one Asterisk to another with passing UUI.
On my asterisk 13 i have a simple dialplan:

```
exten => 2222,1,Answer
exten => 2222,n,Transfer(SIP/1111@asterisk14&User-to-User=342342ef34;encoding=hex)
exten => 2222,n,Hangup
```

I have registered SIP trunk between my asterisk 13 ans asterisk 1.4

```
register => asterisk13:welcome@10.254.2.115/asterisk14
[asterisk14]
type=friend
secret=welcome
context=asterisk14_incomming
host=dynamic
```

and done similar config on the second asterisk
Now I have error:

> Purely numeric hostname (1111), and not a peer--rejecting!

I have read all I can find about this error but cant find how to resolve it.

thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: On `Asterisk14`, please show us the CLI result of `sip show peer 1111`.

Comment: this command shows the same on both asterisk's "peer 1111 not found" 1111 refers to extension with some dialplan on  the second asterisk.

Comment: Ok.  please show the relevant piece of dialplan on `Asterisk14` ... Also, please rig a dummy extension `1313` on `Asterisk13` that calls `1111` on `Asterisk14` and show us the result of a test dial to that.

Comment: on asterisk14 i have very basic dialplan which im trying to reach

Answer (score 3):

No way pass like that. Use SIPAddHeader